# Positioning an Image

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, scaling

- I want to position an image between two sentences (`itemize` items).
- How to scale an image to `width` / `height` of rest of the page left?

---

```
\item Client\_Wallet asks user to set default path for public key/private key credentials, path to store Local Blockchain and path to store received record.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5,width=\linewidth, height=9cm]{fig/firstRun}
     \caption{Setting Default Path}
    \label{fig:architecture}
\end{figure}

\item Each user has unique address generated from public key associated with Client\_Wallet. Client\_Wallet can be used to serve three purposes.
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/ for the positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- About the positioning, I use the `[H]` option provided by the `float` package.
- The remaining text width (*not* page width) is filled in my example.
- You define `scale` plus `width/height` -- that seems redundant.
- I do *not* know how to fill the remaining `height`.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Sentence one.
%
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=50mm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption of Figure.}
\label{fig:LabelOfFigure}
\end{figure}
%
\item Sentence two.
\item Sentence three.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]